# Updating details on Salesforce Certification Verification site

Tags: certification

Does anyone know how to update details on the Salesforce verification site, or where these details are taken from?

The site (in case anyone is unclear where I mean) is:
http://certification.salesforce.com/verification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're taken from [WebAssessor](https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=defaultLogin) I believe (where you take your exams and do release top-ups). If you update your details on there, it should sync up with Salesforce's Certification site.

**Edit:**
I've just updated my details on there now (thanks for reminding me!) but it appears you can't change your log in details, normally the e-mail address you signed up with. I'm going to contact Krypterion now to find out if they can change it their side.

I've submitted a ticket to Salesforce/Krypterion to see if they  can change this and will let you know what they say. Other details can be changed from the "Edit Profile" page, however.

**Edit 2:**
As we discussed, you can change your account details on WebAssessor. Updating the e-mail field in there will update the e-mail address that's searchable on the Certification Site.

Comment: I've updated my details on webassessor too...let's see what happens :)

Comment: @Girbot I've been meaning to do this myself for a while. I've opened a case regarding e-mail (looks like the e-mail search on the certification site points to the username field in WebAssessor, rather than the e-mail field in there). I'll let you know what they say.

Comment: My details have been updated - I did not have to change my Webassessor Login but I did change both my email and the field "Email address associated with your Salesforce account". So it's one of those.

Comment: @Girbot Just tried this myself as well. Looks like it does look at the e-mail field after all. I'll update my answer for this. :)

Comment: @Girbot Updated it now. If this has done the job, mark it as correct so it might help others with similar questions. :)